# Measuring DC Currents

Tags: current-measurement

I developed a board and I like to measure the power for each block. Power can be a few micro amps to a few hundred mAs. (Depending on the block). I have zero ohm resistors at the input of each block so I can insert a DMM.  I don't have the budget for a nice Scope Current probe. What would be a good way to measure individual currents on each block? (I tried to connect the DMM in between but it changes the total load on that block it is not as effective. Shunt resistor is also not preferred since at low currents, I need to put a high value resistor and that impacts the circuits).

If the method could provide measurements up to 10KHz, it would be great.

Are there low cost home-grown measurement probes that are sold that I can use?

Comment: You mean like a shunt resistor, in amp, and voltmeter?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams shunt resistor and two probes change the load on the circuit. I am looking for non-invasive.

Comment: There is no such thing as non-invasive DC current measuring, at least not with any sort of accuracy. The only thing you can hope for is to be as uninvasive as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a headache that anyone who has tried to make such measurements will recognize instantly. Multimeters tend to have **excessively high** shunt resistors for the purpose (to make them cheaper, they drop lots of voltage (like 200mV full scale)- good for *their* circuit, not so good for *yours*), so they tend to unduly affect the circuit being measured.

A solution is to use a much lower shunt resistance and a very low offset voltage so-called "zero drift" op-amp amplifier with a high gain (such as 100).   A 10 ohm resistor will drop 10uV/uA, so a gain of 100 would give you 1mV/uA and you could read it out on your multimeter (200mV range). If your load is 200uA, that's only 2mV of drop.

As it turns out, this market gap has been noticed, and a product was developed which more than meets your specified requirements. The [schematic](http://www.eevblog.com/files/uCurrentRev5schematic.pdf) is published so you could buy the parts and build it, or simply [buy](https://eevblog.myshopify.com/) the finished product.

If you choose to build it, I suggest putting the battery powered gain-of-100 amplifier into a box and using an external shunt customized for each test (assuming such tests are going to be occasional). A low-drift amplifier is useful for other kinds of testing such as thermocouple and load cell testing.

Answer (score 4):

First: What is the resolution that you want to achieve?

Second: Before trying to reinvent the wheel, have a look at how high end measurement equipments are doing the job.

Usually the small res shunt is the used method. And when I said "small res", I mean ~100mΩ or less. Which is very small and should not be noticeable. The sensitivity of such measurements are very high if properly done. My Agilent DMM can measure current up to 100uA with 6.5 digit using 200Ω. If you don't need 6.5 digit the resistance can be reduced.
But 10uA in a 200Ω shunt has a voltage drop of only 0.2mV !

And you are right that, for measuring very small currents and big current, a high value resistor of 200Ω is not good. This is why a DMM has ranges.

It could be of several kind:

- Analog gain: You use a small shunt (~100mΩ) and you switch from one range to another by just changing the gain of the front end instrumentation differential amplifier at the shunt resistor. This has the benefit of allowing you to have several instrumentation differential amplifiers and when one saturates, you look at the result of the other ones. No relays, no data lost during range switching. The drawback is the noise. At some point with very low current and high gain you will basically measure the noise... Fluke portable DMM are using this method. But some has another input with another bigger shut resistor for small current measurement with less noise.
- Shunt resistor range: You use a high-end relay to switch between different ranges of your measurement system. My Agilent 6.5 digit DMM is working that way. The advantage is the reduced noise problem, but the drawback is that it can't measure across the whole instrument range without switching relay and briefly opening the circuit.

Here are the shunt values used for my Agilent DMM:

- 200 Ω for 100 µA - 1 mA
- 2 Ω for 10 mA - 100 mA
- 0.1 Ω for 1 A, 3 A

But first, you should define what is you required resolution. This would define the number of increments required to cover your full range (or sub range if using one of the proposed techniques) and thus the number of bit of your ADC.

If your require a resolution of 1uA with a full range of 1A, then you have to have an ADC with 1'000'000 steps: ~20bits !!! This is a lot! But if you have ranges of measurements, you could have higher res at low current and lower res at high current. And thus the required ADC would have much less bits.

To answer you question much in detail. You should replace your 0Ω resistors by a small shunt resistor that has the biggest value that does not disturb your system and then use a scope differential probe connected right on the pins of the resistor. Differential probes could be expensive but they include a differential amplifier that is placed close to the input probes. You could try to put a standard single ended probe at one pad of the resistor and another single ended probed at the other pad of your shunt, and then use the math of your scope to do the difference.This would be very noisy and may need some calibration to reduce offsets (especially if the scope was not recently calibrated).

This would give you an idea of the current consumption. As I already said, I don't know what is the resolution or accuracy requirements here.

Having the shunt on the low side is not advisable if you are measuring the power consumption of modules on a PCB. Good EMC/EMI/SI practices strongly suggest that you use continuous and strong GND planes. Segregating your GND plane and putting a single point connection between them using a resistor is a bad idea. because the return currents of the inter module communication would all be forced to flow through this resistor and would couple. This would be very bad in a signal integrity point of view.

Answer (score 0):

As Ignacio said, there is no accurate non invasive current measuring for DC. The reason is that there are two effects of the current outside wire : heat and magnetic field. However, both of them are extremely small at typical low currents (mA) and as such will be expensive to measure accurately. Moreover, they will pick up the influence of neighboring mag field out heat sources.

Instead, the usual way to do it is with a very low value shunt resistor, and an instrumentation amplifier to amplify the voltage.

The shunt resistor can be very low resistance and you size it first depending on your max current : suppose you expect 200mA max and you can accept up to 0.01V drop, you choose a 50mOhm shunt.

Then you choose your amplifier gain accordingly to scale your max voltage drop to a few volts. In this example that would be around 100 times, so you'll get plenty bandwidth.

For more bandwidth and less noise, increase the resistor and decrease the gain. For less intrusion, do the opposite.

If you can put the shunt on the low side, you can use a simple (single supply, no need for rail to rail) op-amp as a non inverting amplifier instead of the in-amp - the cmrr won't be a problem - and the wiring and cost will be quite modest.